# Algorithmically change number in String to a subscript

Tags: java, unicode

Alright, I want to make a method for my Chemistry game/project where it would:

- take a String
- then it would take the String, check for numbers, and if there are numbers, turn it into a subscript of that same number.
- return the updated String

My original thoughts was to turn the string into a char array, then make a for loop where I  try Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(char array element)), and if it threw a NumberFormatException it would continue the for loop. If it didn't throw an error, then I retain that number, add it to 2080 (because \u2080 -> \u2089 are the subscript unicodes) and then somehow smush that number back into a char.

I tried to write the code for it, but wasn't sure how to proceed.

```
private String processName(String original)
    {
        char[] or = original.toCharArray();

        int returned = 0;

        for(char character : or)
        {
            try
            {
                returned = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(character));
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                continue;
            }

            if(returned != 0)
            {
                returned += 2080;

                String temp = "\\u" + returned;

                //gave up here
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Remember that `char`s are two bytes, so they can hold the values you want:

```
for(int i = 0; i < or.length; i++)
{
    try
    {
        returned = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(or[i]));
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        continue;
    }

    if(returned != 0)
    {
        or[i] = (char) (returned + 2080);
    }
}
```

You could get rid of some of the cost of converting to an `int` by simply checking if the `char` is a digit and, if it is, adding the appropriate amount, but since this code already works I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly - I guess I didn't know that char primitives were allowed to take an int, thus making that a unicode character! Again, thanks!